# Is providing the ability to violate "shall" requirement w/o generation of a diagnostic message a compiler bug / defect or feature?

Tags: c, constraints, compiler-warnings, requirements

Context: The C standard does not classify diagnostic messages as "warnings" or "errors".

Question: By treating certain "diagnostic messages" as "warnings" and by giving the ability to disable generation of warnings, certain compiler implementations allow to the end user to violate "shall" requirements of the C standard w/o generation of a diagnostic messages. Is this allowance a compiler bug / defect? If not, then how to correctly interpret this case? As a "compiler feature that allows to violate "shall" requirement w/o generation of a diagnostic message"?

Example:

```
#pragma warning( disable : 34 )
typedef int T[];
int main()
{
    return sizeof(T);
}
```

```
$ cl t28.c /Za
<no diagnostic messages, the "shall" requirement [1] is silently violated>
```

[1] ISO/IEC 9899:1990:

> The sizeof operator shall not be applied to an expression that has function type or an incomplete type.

UPD.

1. If `/Za` (Disable Language Extensions) is specified, then `__STDC__` is defined with definition 1.
2. According to `ANSI Conformance` page (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/ansi-conformance?view=msvc-160):

> Microsoft C conforms to the standard for the C language as set forth in the 9899:1990 edition of the ANSI C standard.

3. However, `cl` gives to the end user the ability to disable "shall requirement originated" warnings. Is it a compiler bug / defect or feature? Need to to correctly interpret this case.

Comment: Does the compiler claim to be standard-conforming?  If not, it doesn't have to follow the rules of the standard.  If you omit the `#pragma`, does it generate the warning?  If so, you've deliberately used an extension to suppress a standard-conforming warning (deliberately said "I don't care about you conforming to the standard").  That's your choice — not a good one, but yours to make.  That doesn't make the compiler non-conforming.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler How to correctly interpret providing of the ability to suppress a standard-conforming "shall requirement originated" warning? Bug/defect or feature? (Note: to my knowledge, compilers do not allow to suppress the errors, only warnings.)

Comment: Where the C standard specifies that a conforming implementation shall define `__STDC__` to be 1, there is a logical problem. The C standard can say what conforming implementations do, but it has no jurisdiction over non-conforming implementations. If a particular compiler does not claim to conform to the C standard, then it may define `__STDC__` to be 1 without breaking any rules, since no rules about how `__STDC__` should be defined apply to it. It is just rude.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Is there any solution for this logical problem? Is WG14 aware of this logical problem?

Comment: @pmor: It is impossible to regulate a thing over which one has no jurisdiction, so no standard can ever require non-conforming implementations to distinguish themselves from conforming implementations. I suppose one might register a trademark and then define a symbol name containing that trademark and use legal jurisdictions to prohibit non-conforming implementations from using their trademark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C 2018 6.10.6 discusses the `#pragma` directive. Paragraph 1 says:

> … causes the implementation to behave in an implementation-defined manner. The behavior might cause translation to fail or cause the translator or the resulting program to behave in a non-conforming manner…

That largely licenses the implementation to do anything it wants, as long as it documents it. If `#pragma warning( disable : 34 )` is documented to disable the warning, and that is what it does, then that is conforming.

Note in particular that the `#pragma` “might … cause the translator … to behave in a non-conforming manner.” So, doing something that is otherwise non-conforming because a pragma told you to is conforming.

(I think the original text should say that the `#pragma` may cause the translator or program to behave in an **otherwise** non-conforming manner. Because, as currently written, behaving in this documented non-conforming manner is conforming, not non-conforming.)

Answer (score 0):

"shall" (and "shall not") requirements in the standard come in two distinct kinds: restrictions on the *program* and restrictions on the *implementation*.

Restrictions on the *implemention* are things the implementation must (or must not) do -- these may have mandatory diagnostics associated with them.

Restrictions on the *program* are in fact *freedoms* for the implementation -- they are things that -- if the program does them -- cause undefined behavior, so the implementation can do anything with them and still be conforming.

The example you have above "The sizeof operator shall not be applied to an expression that "... is a restriction on the *program*.  So a program that does that is not conforming and an implementation can do anything it wants (including treating it as an extension without any requirement for a flag or pragma) and still be conforming.