# Is there any C compiler which defines both __STDC__ and __STDC_IEC_559__ to 1?

Tags: c, floating-point, ieee-754, c11, standards-compliance

Is there any C compiler(s) which defines both `__STDC__` and `__STDC_IEC_559__` to 1?

If so, then which one(s)?

Reason of the question: as far as I can test (April 2021), none of the latest versions of popular C compilers (gcc, clang, msvc) define both `__STDC__` and `__STDC_IEC_559__` to 1. Hence, these compilers may generate executable files, which produce non-IEEE 754 conformant results. However, there is a demand on such C compilers, which actually provide a guarantee / confidence that generated executable files produce IEEE 754 conformant results (under `strict` floating-point model option).

Comment: Why do you wonder? Is there an underlying problem you need to solve, or just plain curiosity? If it's curiosity then please tell us, otherwise please ask us directly about the problem.

Comment: @pmor You may need to set appropriate compiler switches for maximum IEEE-754 compliance. I tried the latest release versions of gcc, icc, and clang for x86-64 at [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org) and with `-frounding-math -fsignaling-nans` all three report both `__STDC__` and `__STDC_IEC_559__` as `1`.

Comment: @user3386109 Strictly speaking, C11 (or any edition of the C standard) requires *conforming* compilers to define `__STDC__` as `1`. (Non-conforming compilers can do anything they like.)

Comment: @pmor No matter what command line switches I try, MSVC 2019 doesn't seem to define either `__STDC__` or `__STDC_IEC_559__`. It tried `/fp:strict` in conjunction with all available C and C++ `/std:` switch settings.

Comment: @njuffa `__STDC_IEC_559__ as 1`: Many thanks for the confirmation! It turns out that `__STDC_IEC_559__` value (if defined) depends of the host OS. For example, both gcc 10.2.0 (with `-frounding-math -fsignaling-nans`) and clang 11.0.1 (with `-ffp-model=strict`) running on Windows 10 (version 2004) do not define `__STDC_IEC_559__ to 1`.

Comment: @KeithThompson Thanks for noting this aspect. It was mentioned in comments for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65744941/1778275) question as well.

Comment: @njuffa FYI: `cl.exe` version `19.28.29913` under `/std:c11 /Za` does define `__STDC__` to `1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It turned out that in gcc and clang definition of `__STDC_IEC_559__` depends on the host OS. In case of Windows: `__STDC_IEC_559__` is `0`. In case of Linux: `__STDC_IEC_559__` is `1`.

Here are the options to get both `__STDC__` and `__STDC_IEC_559__` defined to `1`:

```
clang -std=c11 -ffp-model=strict
gcc -std=c11 -frounding-math -fsignaling-nans
```

UPD20211229: Intel C compiler defines both `__STDC__` and `__STDC_IEC_559__` to `1`:

```
icc -std=c11 -fp-model=strict
```